# What effect to SPF-record qualifiers have if they are included into another SPF record, if the parent record is stricter than the child?

Tags: web-services, email, sendmail, spf

I want to put a strict FAIL qualifier on all email sources that are not listed explicitly in the SPF record of my domain.

This can simply be accomplished by the following record (the `-all` designates that all other sources should not be accepted)

```
mydomain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 ip4:my-ip-address/32 -all"
```

Now my problem is that I in addition want to white-list my email provider (mailgun.com) as well as google apps, so I created the following record:

```
mydomain.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org include:_spf.google.com ip4:my-ip-address/32 -all"
```

Now the SPF record of `mailgun.com` (in case of google the same situation applies) resolves to:

```
mailgun.org.        3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 ip4:173.193.210.32/27 ip4:50.23.218.192/27 ip4:174.37.226.64/27 ip4:208.43.239.136/30 ip4:50.23.215.176/30 ip4:184.173.105.0/24 ip4:184.173.153.0/24 ip4:209.61.151.0/24 ip4:166.78.68.0/22 ip4:198.61.254.0/23 ip4:192.237.158.0/23 " "~all"
```

Now what,s interesting is, is, that they put a soft fail qualifier `"~all"` on their spf record.

Wikipedia describes the include directive as follows:

> If the included (a misnomer) policy passes the test this mechanism
>   matches. This is typically used to include policies of more than one
>   ISP.

I interpret this in the way that an unknown sender is qualified as `SOFT FAIL` by the included records, and therefore passes as `SOFT FAIL`, because they are included in the root record. Even if the root record puts a `FAIL` on all not included sources.

So that the incldued records effectively render the FAIL qualifier of the root record useless. So the laeast strict record deinfes the overall qualifier for unknown sources.

Am I correct in this assumption? If not, how is in the example given, an unknown sender qualified?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is described in seciton 5.2 of the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt)  where it says

```
   Whether this mechanism matches, does not match, or throws an
   exception depends on the result of the recursive evaluation of
   check_host():

   +---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
   | A recursive check_host() result | Causes the "include" mechanism  |
   | of:                             | to:                             |
   +---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
   | Pass                            | match                           |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | Fail                            | not match                       |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | SoftFail                        | not match                       |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | Neutral                         | not match                       |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | TempError                       | throw TempError                 |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | PermError                       | throw PermError                 |
   |                                 |                                 |
   | None                            | throw PermError                 |
   +---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

The mechanism in this contects refers to the "include" functionality.

As shown in the table a softfail causes a not-match.

It also says:

```
   In hindsight, the name "include" was poorly chosen.  Only the
   evaluated result of the referenced SPF record is used, rather than
   acting as if the referenced SPF record was literally included in the
   first.
```

Which I interpret in the way that only the result of the included record is relevant, which is, in the cas of a soft fail, a not-match (same as if the record woul have a FAIL) qualifier.

Here's also a test result with the py spf library performed on this [website](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html?)

```
Input accepted, querying now...


Mail sent from this IP address: 1.2.3.4 
Mail from (Sender): scknpbi@cacxjxv.com 
Mail checked using this SPF policy: v=spf1 ip4:4.5.6.7/32 include:mailgun.org -all 
Results - FAIL Message may be rejected


Mail sent from: 1.2.3.4 
Mail Server HELO/EHLO identity: blanivzsrxvbla@saucjw.com 

HELO/EHLO Results - none
```

Comment: Just to verify: does this mean that it never makes any difference if the included rules has `-all` or `~all` at the end? If I understood correctly, whole included rule is always totally ignored unless the verification result is `Pass` for that specific include as a whole. And logically `+all` in the included rule will always cause top level Pass, too.